# submit canvas images in post ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-canvas

I have a form that contains some canvas images and other form elements
I need to submit these data all together in one ajax post request.
Unfortunatly , I am getting this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

```
$sheet_items_div.on('submit','form',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $form=$(this);
    var url = $form.attr('action');
    var fd = new FormData();
    $form.find('canvas').each(function(idx,el){
        datauri=$(el).data('sketch').download('image/png');
        file=dataURItoBlob(datauri); //custom function
        fd[el.id]=file;
    });
    $.each($form.serializeArray(),function(idx,el){ // to append non canvas elements
        fd[el.name]=el.value;
    });
    debugger;
    $.post(url,fd,function(responce){
        //...
    });
});
```

Comment: On what part of the code this Type error is thrown ?

Comment: when calling the request.